# как презентацию сделать просматриваемым но чтобы невозможно было его скачать с сайта?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

как презентацию сделать просматриваемым но чтобы невозможно было его скачать с сайта??? помогите!!! спасибо

Comment: По идее ни как, можно сделать просто очень сложно.

Comment: никак. Любые ваши попытки сведутся к тому, что навыки скачивающего должны будут быть чуть выше. И даже когда вам покажется, что вы наконец победили, он сделает скриншоты.

Comment: если будут скриншотить не проблема главное чтобы  не скачивали

Answer (score 1):

Организуйте показ ваших материалов через javascript посредством [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) (а подгружаемые материалы, можно дополнительно разрезать и склеивать их при показе. такой подход ранее использовал [google.com/culturalinstitute](http://www.google.com/culturalinstitute/beta/), но я все равно скачал каждый кусочек картины и склеил воедино. ...очень нужно было.). 100% гарантии от кражи это не дает, но таким образом вы усложните жизнь тем кому действительно нужно скачать ваши материалы, а не просто онлайн просмотреть.

В таком случае, можно эффективнее прятать источник презентации и максимум, что остается это на каждом слайде вашей презентации пользователю придется кликать правой кнопкой мыши и нажимать "сохранить картинку"(либо делать скриншоты), и вы знаете, правый щелчок мыши, тоже можно отследить и вместо вызова стандартного контекстного меню, сделать свое какое нибудь действие.

Просмотрел сейчас гугл арт проджект. у них канваса нет, просто разрезаные картинки в кучке дивов.
[image: Пример техники разрезанных картинок]

Пример просмотра изображений с помощью canvas: http://dovela-datz.com/js/slider/demo/

Статья рассказывающая о том как сделать свое пользовательское меню на javascript: https://habrahabr.ru/post/258167/

Answer (score 0):

Можно на сайте заблокировать нажатие правой кнопки мыши, если вы админ сайта. Но это поможет только против IE и гуглехрома. На Мозилле и Опере легко обходится. Можно поставить защиту на сам файл. Но это легко обходится при использовании ОпенОфиса. Так что, как это не печально - НИКАК.

Comment: да пофигу на вашу правую кнопку. ф12 - просмотр кода страницы.